# Show that $\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})<\infty$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a discrete Random Variable with values in $\left\{1,2,3,\ldots\right\}$. It is to show that
$$
\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})<\infty.
$$
As a hinbt it is given that it suffices to show that
$$
P(X>k)\leqslant e^{-ck}
$$
for some $c>0$.

Could you please explain to me why this suffices?

I only know that
$$
\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{tn}\cdot P(X=n).
$$

Comment: What is the probability mass function of X? What are the restrictions on t?

Comment: Dont know the mass function of $X$. This is just the moment generating function, so I think $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: We must have some additional constraint since Jensen's inequality gives $$\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]\geq e^{t\mathbb{E}[X]},$$ so if $\mathbb{E}[X]=+\infty$, the same happens for $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$ with $t>0$.

Comment: What you say you want to prove is not so. If the problem is correct there's something you're not telling us. To show that expectation is finite requires some information on the _distribution_ of $X$.

Comment: Probably the correct statement would be: given that $\mathbb{P}[X>k]\leq e^{-ck}$ for any $k$ and some positive constant $c$, show that $\mathbb{E}[e^{t X}]$ is finite for any $t>0$.

Comment: @Jack May be that it is formulated wrongly and must be the way you wrote it. But why does it follow then?

Comment: And does this hold only for t>0 or in a neighborhood of t=0?

Comment: @Salamo: I have just written an answer to the "fixed" statement.

Comment: "Probably the correct statement would be:" imo it's much better for the guy in the long run if you don't answer the question until _he_ gives a correct statement! He presumably has a correct statement in front of him; he's not likely to learn to get any of this right as long as he's at the stage where he can't even copy the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must have some additional constraint since Jensen's inequality gives $$\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]\geq e^{t\mathbb{E}[X]},$$ so if $\mathbb{E}[X]=+\infty$, the same happens for $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$ with $t>0$.

> A correct statement is: given that for some positive constant $c$
>   $$\forall k\in\mathbb{N},\quad \mathbb{P}[X>k]\leq e^{-ck}$$ holds,
>   show that $\mathbb{E}[e^{t X}]$ is finite for any $t\in(0,c)$.

To provide an upper bound for $\mathbb{E}[e^{t X}]$, it is enough to provide good bounds for the moments $\mathbb{E}[X^n]$, then exploit the fact that the exponential function is an entire function. Since:
$$\mathbb{P}[X^n>k]\leq e^{-c k^{1/n}},$$
it follows that:
$$\mathbb{E}[X^n]=\sum_{k\geq 1}\mathbb{P}[X^n>k] \leq \sum_{k\geq 1}e^{-c k^{1/n}}\leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-c k^{1/n}}\,dk=\frac{n!}{c^n}$$
hence:
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{t^n \mathbb{E}[X^n]}{n!}\leq\frac{1}{1-\frac{t}{c}}.$$

Comment: Does this mean, that the moment generating function exists in a neighborhood of 0?

Comment: @Salamo: yes, it does.

Comment: How do you get $P(X^n>k)\leqslant e^{-ck^{1/n}}$?

Comment: @Salamo: from $\mathbb{P}[X>k]\leq e^{-ck}$. Consider that $\mathbb{P}[X^n>k]=\mathbb{P}[X>k^{1/n}]$.

Comment: One last (hope not too stupid). How do you get the estimation from the sum to the integral?

Comment: @Salamo: it is just the usual series-integral bound for decreasing functions.

Comment: You mean this http://modular.math.washington.edu/20b/notes/html/node45.html with $R_m=R_0$, right?

Comment: @Salamo: yes, exactly.

Comment: I have computed that $P(X>k)\leq (\frac{8}{9})^{k/2}$. So is there a $c>0$ such that $(8/9)^{k/2}\leq e^{-ck}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Salamo: I'd say so, just take $c=\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{9}{8}$.